# Accepted answer checkmark color

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, accepted-answer

When I ask a question (and every answer has a check mark next to it for me to select one as my accepted answer), it's very hard for me to tell the difference between the check mark that I've checked, and one that I haven't checked.

Could you either use a brighter green for the one that I've checked, or make the unchecked ones appear as an outline like on StackOverflow?

Comment: Do you have a form of green colorblindness? I ask because the checkbox as it is right now is bright green.

Comment: Yes, I'm red-green blind. I guess I'm asking for a darker green or a lighter grey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ken, thank you for bringing this to my attention. We take accessibility pretty seriously. I have adjusted the contrast between accepted and non-accepted arrows. should be in the next deployment. Be sure to refresh your browser since the images are sprited on the site.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a big difference just now when I accepted your answer.